# R dplyr count occurences of separate events in time series data

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I'm a bit of a noob with dplyr, and I know it's an easy fix. I have data of certain events, "X","Y",and "Z" and a list of dates on which those events occured. An example can be generated by the following:

```
days.14<-seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"),as.Date("2014/12/31"),by="days")
X<-c("X","")
Y<-c("Y","")
Z<-c("Z","")
data<-as.data.frame(sample(days.14,200,replace=TRUE))
data$X<-sample(X,200,replace=TRUE)
data$Y<-sample(Y,200,replace=TRUE)
data$Z<-sample(Z,200,replace=TRUE)
names(data)[1]<-"date"
data<-data[order(as.Date(data$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")),]
```

I'm trying to use the dplyr package to take counts for each event grouped by the day. So, rather than a row in the data representing the days where events happened it would be all the days in the data set with the number of times each event happened. So instead of something like this:

```
2014-01-01     Z
2014-01-01   Y Z
2014-01-01 X
2014-01-02 X Y Z
```

I'm tryig to use dplyr to get :

```
  date        X Y Z
--------------------
2014-01-01    1 1 2
2014-01-01    1 1 1
```

The code I've used to accomplish this doesn't work for character vectors.

```
counts = data%>% group_by(factor(date))%>%
summarise(X=sum(X),
Y=sum(Y),
Z=sum(Z))
```

The way I usually generate counts is through the table function but that doesn't work for dplyr.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` before drawing random samples to construct an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(date) %>%
         summarise_each(funs(sum(.!="")), -date)
```

For completeness, a data.table solution from @David-Arenburg:

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x != "")), by = date]
```

Your problem is that you are trying to sum the row, which as the row is not numeric, doesn't work.

You need to check that the X, Y or Z is not `""` instead (`NA` is more widely used as a blank in r).

We can use `summarise_each` to do this on each row, with the `-date` making sure the date column is not included.

NB if you just wanted to fix your code, here's the easiest solution:

```
data %>% group_by(date)%>%
         summarise(X = sum(X == "X"),
                   Y = sum(Y == "Y"),
                   Z = sum(Z == "Z"))
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way

```
set.seed(1000)
days.14<-seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"),as.Date("2014/12/31"),by="days")
X<-c("X","")
Y<-c("Y","")
Z<-c("Z","")
data<-as.data.frame(sample(days.14,200,replace=TRUE))
data$X<-sample(X,200,replace=TRUE)
data$Y<-sample(Y,200,replace=TRUE)
data$Z<-sample(Z,200,replace=TRUE)
names(data)[1]<-"date"
data<-data[order(as.Date(data$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")),]
library(reshape2)
```

using melt to consolidate all X,Y,Z

```
summ<-data%>%melt(id.var="date")%>% group_by(factor(date))%>%summarize(X = sum(value=="X"), Y = sum(value=="Y"), Z = sum(value=="Z"))

head(as.data.frame(summ))  

  factor(date) X Y Z
1   2014-01-04 0 1 1
2   2014-01-05 1 1 0
3   2014-01-08 1 2 1
4   2014-01-09 1 0 0
5   2014-01-10 1 1 1
6   2014-01-14 2 2 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to `recast` (`melt` -> `dcast`) the data

```
library(reshape2)
recast(data, date ~ variable, id.var = 1, fun.aggregate = function(x) sum(x != ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to accomplish this task using ddply:

```
    ddply(data,.(date),function(x){
  xcount <- sum(grep("X",x$X))
  ycount <- sum(grep("Y",x$Y))
  zcount <- sum(grep("Z",x$Z))
  data.frame(X=xcount,Y=ycount,Z=zcount)
})
```